# Sonarqube shows some projects are passed others failed by default

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I have 20 projects in Sonarqube. The results show me that half of them passed, while others failed by default. Since this is newly installed, I don't start working out on any of them. I know projects should go beyond 80% code coverage to result in passes (by doing unit tests). Currently, none of them have unit tests. I wonder why some of them failed and others passed.

PS: Projects are scanned through Azure DevOps pipelines with the same configuration.

[image]